# Own template for leaf nodes in a WPF TreeView with unknown levels

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to add checkboxes to the leaf nodes in a TreeView in WPF. I know how to do this if we have a fixed number of levels in the hierarchy and using a HierarchicalDataTemplate for each level. But what to do when I want this:
-Node 1
-- Node 1a (leaf node with checkbox)
-- Node 1b
--- Node 1bI (leaf node with checkbox)
-Node 2
-- Node 2a (leaf node with checkbox)

I set the DataContext in the code file to a DataTable. Just one table, with a relation to it self.

```
DataContext = ds.MyDataTable;
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="JostyWpfControls.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Height="240" Width="312">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding myDatasetRelation}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChosen}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </CheckBox>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is working, but gives me a chechbox to all nodes. I just want the leaf nodes to have a checkbox.

Comment: Could you provide some of the XAML you already have, as a starting point to providing an answer for you?

Comment: I edited my question and added my XAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a trigger in the data template to determine whether the checkbox should be visible:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding myDatasetRelation}">
  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChosen}" 
              Content="{Binding Description}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="LeafLabel" Text="{Binding Description}"
               Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </StackPanel>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myDatasetRelation.Count}" Value="0">
      <Setter TargetName="CheckBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      <Setter TargetName="LeafLabel" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I'm not sure whether the value bound to via `myDatasetRelation` has a `Count` property, but if not then you could use `Length` or find some other way to determine whether it's empty or not (perhaps using an `IValueConverter` if no simpler approach is available.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it worked as I typed it from memory which often doesn't work first time.